# Fluentd: - problem with regex while parsing log

Tags: regex, fluentd

I have this `fluentd` configuration:

```xml
<source>
   @type tail
   <parse>
   @type regexp
    expression /^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] \"(?<method>\w+) (?<path>[^ ]*) (?<http>[^ ]*)" (?<status_code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?:\s"(?<referer>[^\"]*)") "(?<agent>[^\"]*)" (?<urt>[^\"]*).*/
      time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
      keep_time_key true
      types size:integer,reqtime:float,uct:float,uht:float,urt:float
   </parse>
   path /var/log/nginx/access.log
   pos_file /tmp/fluent_nginx.pos
   tag nginx
</source>
```

My log format:

```
193.137.78.17 - - [07/Jan/2023:09:21:59 +0000] "GET /net/api/employee HTTP/1.1" 200 2323 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.014
193.137.78.17 - - [07/Jan/2023:09:22:00 +0000] "GET /net/api/employee HTTP/1.1" 200 2323 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.005
```

I've tested my regex on regex101 and works without problems. Still, I get a no patterns matched warning on fluentd. I don't understand why the log isn't parsed correctly.

```
Jan 07 09:26:26 srv-api fluentd[14878]: 2023-01-07 09:26:26 +0000 [warn]: #0 no patterns matched tag="nginx"
```

Can anyone help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected result from the sample log you provided ?

Comment: Instead of the [regexp parser plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/regexp), did you try to use the [nginx parser plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/nginx) directly?

Answer (score 0):

#### I think your problem is leading spaces in the log

Your pattern is insisting that the `<remote>` has no spaces before it, but you do have 4 spaces in your log before the remote IP.

The simplest way, to my mind, is to insert an optional variable-number-of-spaces at the beginning.

```
^( )*(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] \"(?<method>\w+) (?<path>[^ ]*) (?<http>[^ ]*)" (?<status_code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?:\s"(?<referer>[^\"]*)") "(?<agent>[^\"]*)" (?<urt>[^\"]*).*
```

#### How it works

The `(` and `)` are just to make life easier for people reading the code: they will see that between them is a space character, which they might not otherwise notice.

The `*` means 0 or more of these.

This allows 0 or more spaces at the beginning of the line to be matched and discarded.

#### Incidentally

I noticed you are sometimes escaping `"` with `\` and sometimes not. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I'm really useless at regex. That's why several things are not donne correctly...

Comment: Heh heh, it takes a lot of getting used to! Did the answer help you? If so please mark it as accepted (green checkmark).

Comment: @Eureka: I believe that those preceding whitespaces were added due to the formatting and the actual error (`no patterns matched tag="nginx"`) was due to the absence of a respective `match` section. The same error is reproducible by missing the handling of a tag. Thought you might want to know. I have added the details in my answer as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should directly use the [nginx parser plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/nginx) instead.

Here is a complete working example with the [sample input plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/sample) and the [nginx](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/nginx) [parser](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser) plugin:

**fluent-nginx-test.conf**

```xml
<source>
  @type sample
  sample [
    { "message": "193.137.78.17 - - [07/Jan/2023:09:22:00 +0000] \"GET /net/api/employee HTTP/1.1\" 200 2323 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\" 0.005" },
    { "message": "193.137.78.18 - - [07/Jan/2023:09:22:00 +0000] \"GET /net/api/employee HTTP/1.1\" 200 2323 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\" 0.005" }
  ]
  rate 1
  size 2
  tag nginx
</source>

<filter nginx>
  @type parser
  key_name message
  <parse>
    @type nginx
  </parse>
</filter>

<match nginx>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

**Run**

```bash
$ fluentd -c ./fluent-nginx-test.conf
```

**Output**

```
2023-01-07 14:22:00.000000000 +0500 nginx: {"remote":"193.137.78.17","host":"-","user":"-","method":"GET","path":"/net/api/employee","code":"200","size":"2323","referer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","http_x_forwarded_for":"0.005"}
2023-01-07 14:22:00.000000000 +0500 nginx: {"remote":"193.137.78.18","host":"-","user":"-","method":"GET","path":"/net/api/employee","code":"200","size":"2323","referer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","http_x_forwarded_for":"0.005"}
```

---

Apart from that, I used your regex with the [regexp parser plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/regexp) and it's working fine too (though there are redundant values in `types` field):

**fluent-nginx-test-with-regexp.conf**

```xml
<source>
  @type sample
  sample [
    { "message": "193.137.78.17 - - [07/Jan/2023:09:22:00 +0000] \"GET /net/api/employee HTTP/1.1\" 200 2323 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\" 0.005" },
    { "message": "193.137.78.18 - - [07/Jan/2023:09:22:00 +0000] \"GET /net/api/employee HTTP/1.1\" 200 2323 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\" 0.005" }
  ]
  rate 1
  size 2
  tag nginx
</source>

<filter nginx>
  @type parser
  key_name message
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] \"(?<method>\w+) (?<path>[^ ]*) (?<http>[^ ]*)" (?<status_code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?:\s"(?<referer>[^\"]*)") "(?<agent>[^\"]*)" (?<urt>[^\"]*).*/
    time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
    keep_time_key true
    types size:integer,reqtime:float,uct:float,uht:float,urt:float
   </parse>
</filter>

<match nginx>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

**Run**

```bash
$ fluentd -c ./fluent-nginx-test-with-regexp.conf
```

**Output**

```
2023-01-07 14:22:00.000000000 +0500 nginx: {"remote":"193.137.78.17","host":"-","user":"-","time":"07/Jan/2023:09:22:00 +0000","method":"GET","path":"/net/api/employee","http":"HTTP/1.1","status_code":"200","size":2323,"referer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","urt":0.005}
2023-01-07 14:22:00.000000000 +0500 nginx: {"remote":"193.137.78.18","host":"-","user":"-","time":"07/Jan/2023:09:22:00 +0000","method":"GET","path":"/net/api/employee","http":"HTTP/1.1","status_code":"200","size":2323,"referer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","urt":0.005}
```

However, the error `no patterns matched tag="nginx"` in message:

```
Jan 07 09:26:26 srv-api fluentd[14878]: 2023-01-07 09:26:26 +0000 [warn]: #0 no patterns matched tag="nginx"
```

which means that you don't have a corresponding `match` section in your config file. You must have a `match` section with the respective `tag` that you want to process or output.

Example:

```xml
<source>
  @type tail
  # ...
  tag nginx
</source>

# ...

<match nginx>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

- You should take a look at the [config file syntax](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file) specifically [How do the match patterns work?](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#how-do-the-match-patterns-work) section for more guidelines.
- Also, you might want to use the [vscode-fluentd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msysyamamoto.vscode-fluentd) extension for syntax highlighting with [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

---

**Environment**

- `fluentd`

```bash
$ fluentd --version
fluentd 1.12.3
```

- **OS**

```bash
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
```